# Помогите перебрать массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, перебор

Есть вот такой объект:

```
const input = {
    foo: [1,2,3,4,5],
    bar: [6,7],
    baz: [8,9,10,11],
    mix: [12,13,14],
};
```

Количество данных (ключей и массивов) может быть произвольным, помогите найти все возможные варианты вертикальных пересечений.

Я написал код конкретно для этого массива, он работает, но понимаю, что это глупость, хочется универсальное решение:

```
const output = [];
                
input.foo.map((foo)=>{

    input.bar.map((bar)=>{

        input.baz.map((baz)=>{

            input.mix.map((mix)=>{

                output.push({
                    foo,
                    bar,
                    baz,
                    mix,
                });

            });

        });

    });

});

console.log(output);
```

Результат в итоге должен получится [таким](http://joxi.ru/KAxnZGYI1vbJ7m) но работать с любым входящим массивом. Ломал голову с рекурсией, так ничего и не получилось, заранее большое спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не очень удобно исходные данные заданы, массивом было бы лучше. Но не суть.
Данную задачу можно решить как при помощи рекурсии, так и без нее.

Сначала хотел бы рассмотреть вариант без рекурсии.
Можно представить себе счетчик электроэнергии или воды, не важно, хоть обычное десятичное число.
Когда один разряд переполняется, то старший увеличивается на единицу, текущий начинает отсчет с 0, и так далее по цепочке.
Только в нашем случае, основание у каждого разряда может быть различным.
Поэтому мы заведем массив-счетчик и массив оснований. Основание соответствует количеству элементов в массиве.
Число всех комбинаций получим как произведение всех оснований.

Принцип работы счетчика прост: прибавляем единицу по модулю основания. Если результат 0, то надо проделать это со следующим разрядом, и т.д.
Это удобно реализовать с помощью метода [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

Перебираем все комбинации в цикле, записываем комбинацию в результирующий массив, увеличиваем счетчик. Привожу пример под Ваши данные так, чтобы легче было понять суть:

```js
const input = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  bar: [6, 7],
  baz: [8, 9, 10, 11],
  mix: [12, 13, 14],
};

let counter = [0, 0, 0, 0];
let bases   = [3, 4, 2, 5];
let total   = 5 * 2 * 4 * 3;
let result  = [];

for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  result.push({
    'foo': input.foo[counter[3]],
    'bar': input.bar[counter[2]],
    'baz': input.baz[counter[1]],
    'mix': input.mix[counter[0]],
  });

  counter.some((e, ci) => (counter[ci] = (e + 1) % bases[ci]));
}

console.log(result);
```

Осталось обобщить это для любого набора данных:

```js
const input = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  bar: [6, 7],
  baz: [8, 9, 10, 11],
  mix: [12, 13, 14],
};

let entries = Object.entries(input);
let counter = Array(entries.length).fill(0);
let bases   = entries.map(e => e[1].length).reverse();
let total   = bases.reduce((acc, v) => acc * v);
let s       = entries.length - 1;
let result  = [];

for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  result.push(
    entries.reduce((r, v, i) => (r[v[0]] = v[1][counter[s - i]], r), {})
  );

  counter.some((e, ci) => (counter[ci] = (e + 1) % bases[ci]));
}

console.log(result);
```

**UPD.** Еще один вариант на очередях:

```js
const input = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  bar: [6, 7],
  baz: [8, 9, 10, 11],
  mix: [12, 13, 14],
};

let entries = Object.entries(input);
let keys = Object.keys(input);
let size = entries.length;
let queue = [];
let result = [];

queue.push(entries[0][1]);

let row = {};
let i = 0;

while (i >= 0) {
  if (queue[i].length == 0) {
    i--;
    queue.pop();
  } else {
    row[keys[i]] = queue[i].shift();

    if (i < size - 1)
      queue.push(entries[++i][1].slice());
    else
      result.push(Object.assign({}, row));
  }
};

console.log(result);
```

Ну и вариант с рекурсией:

```js
const input = {
  foo: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  bar: [6, 7],
  baz: [8, 9, 10, 11],
  mix: [12, 13, 14],
};

let entries = Object.entries(input);
const size  = entries.length;
let result  = [];

function walkEntries(row = {}, idx = 0) {
  let e = entries[idx];

  for (let i = 0; i < e[1].length; i++) {
    row[e[0]] = e[1][i];

    if (idx < size - 1)
      walkEntries(row, idx + 1);
    else
      result.push(Object.assign({}, row));
  }
}

walkEntries();
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Вы просто лучший!! Спасибо большое за развернутые ответы, вариант на очередях вообще какая-то магия, только после десятого раза, разобрался)

Comment: Спасибо, рад что оказался полезен. Задача очень понравилась, поэтому столько вариантов налепил ;)